# SAS finding an uppercase word within a string

Tags: string, sas

I have a string which contains one word in uppercase somewhere within it.  I want to extract that one word into a new variable using SAS.

I think I need to find a way to code up finding a word which contains two or more uppercase letters (as the start of a sentence would begin with an uppercase letter).

i.e. How do I create the variable 'word':

```
data example;

    length txtString $50;

    length word $20;

    infile datalines dlm=',';

    input txtString $ word $;

datalines;

This is one EXAMPLE. Of what I need.,EXAMPLE

THIS is another.,THIS

etc ETC,ETC

;

run;
```

Hope someone can help and the question is clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: set up a for loop for the length of the string and then use the byte function to check for uppercase ascii values

Answer (score 0):

Consider a regex match/replace with a negative lookbehind to include two types of matches:

1. consecutive upper case words followed by a space with at least two characters (to avoid title cases at beginning of sentence): `(([A-Z ]){2,})`
2. consecutive upper case words followed by a period with at least two characters: (to avoid title cases at beginning of sentence): `(([A-Z.]){2,})`

CAVEAT: This solution works except the **I** article is also matched which technically is a valid match as it is also an all uppercase one-word. Being the only type in English language, consider a `tranwrd()` replace for such a special case. In fact, relatedly, this solution matches ALL uppercase words.

```
data example;
    length txtString $50;
    length word $20;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    input txtString $ word $;
datalines;
This is one EXAMPLE. Of what I need.,EXAMPLE
THIS is another.,THIS
etc ETC,ETC
;
run;

data example;
    set example;
    pattern_num = prxparse("s/(?!(([A-Z ]){2,})|(([A-Z.]){2,})).//");
    wordextract = prxchange(pattern_num, -1, txtString); 

    wordextract = tranwrd(wordextract, " I ", "");
    drop pattern_num;
run;

txtString                               word     wordextract
This is one EXAMPLE. Of what I need.    EXAMPLE  EXAMPLE
THIS is another.                        THIS     THIS
etc ETC                                 ETC      ETC
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS has a prxsubstr() function call that finds the starting position and length of a substring that matches a given regex pattern within a given string. Here's a sample solution using the prxsubstr() function call:

```
data solution;
    set example;

    /* Build a regex pattern of the word to search for, and hang on to it */
    /* (The regex below means: word boundary, then two or more capital letters, 
    then word boundary. Word boundary here means the start or the end of a string
    of letters, digits and/or underscores.) */
    if _N_ = 1 then pattern_num = prxparse("/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/");
    retain pattern_num;

    /* Get the starting position and the length of the word to extract */
    call prxsubstr(pattern_num, txtString, mypos, mylength);

    /* If a word matching the regex pattern is found, extract it */
    if mypos ^= 0 then word = substr(txtString, mypos, mylength);
run;
```

SAS prxsubstr() documentation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295971.htm

Regex word boundary info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html